# How can i make grids in SFML window?

Tags: c++, sfml

im new at SFML C++ and im trying to make grids on my Render window.
I searched in the internet and i saw some very complicated ways to do that.
Is any one knows a simple way to do the grids on the window?

Comment: You will likely need to draw the lines yourself - see https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-shape.php#built-in-shape-types

Answer (score 0):

In SFML there isn't a direct way to draw grids on a window. The simplest approach I can come with is the following:

```
void drawGrid(sf::RenderWindow& win, int rows, int cols){
    // initialize values
    int numLines = rows+cols-2;
    sf::VertexArray grid(sf::Lines, 2*(numLines));
    win.setView(win.getDefaultView());
    auto size = win.getView().getSize();
    float rowH = size.y/rows;
    float colW = size.x/cols;
    // row separators
    for(int i=0; i < rows-1; i++){
        int r = i+1;
        float rowY = rowH*r;
        grid[i*2].position = {0, rowY};
        grid[i*2+1].position = {size.x, rowY};
    }
    // column separators
    for(int i=rows-1; i < numLines; i++){
        int c = i-rows+2;
        float colX = colW*c;
        grid[i*2].position = {colX, 0};
        grid[i*2+1].position = {colX, size.y};
    }
    // draw it
    win.draw(grid);
}
```

This will do the most basic grid you can think of, but maybe you can get some ideas to further customize it.